# Is it possible to use C++ code in html5?

Tags: c++, html, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to make an app for which i need to include a part of my c++ code for calculation. For GUI i'm using HTML5. So is it possible to include C++ code into HTML5 ?

Comment: Are you trying to embed C++ in html5. Else you can't use C++ in HTML.

Comment: Why do you ask, and what concrete C++ code do you want to use in HTML5? Edit your question to improve it and be more precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can't do that. Try porting your C++ to JavaScript. You could take a look at [this](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) project that claims it can convert C++ code to JavaScript. I have never tried this myself.

Otherwise, you could write a CGI to use your C++ program and use AJAX to "remote execute it".

Answer (score 2):

It is not easily possible to use C++ code in HTML5; but it depends what you really want to do.

You should first understand what [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) and [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) really are, and where you want the C++ code to run (in the browser - on the HTTP client side, or in the server - on the HTTP server side).

If you want to use C++ code on the client side (in the browser), you probably want something like [Google Native Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client). Not all browsers are supporting it, and your user needs to enable it. You could also consider compiling your C++ code to Javascript with [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki).

If you want C++ code on the server side, you may want to use [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) or [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) techniques, or make your C++ code a specialized HTTP server by using some HTTP server library (like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt))

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3849858/841108).